# Modeling time in multilevel logistic regression

Tags: time-series, logistic, multilevel-analysis, mixed-model

I conducted an experiment in which participants listened to sentences while looking at pictures about the sentences on a computer screen. Whether at a given time point a participant looked at the left half of a picture or the right half of a picture was recorded via an eye-tracker.

The study had a 2 by 2 within subjects and within items design. If time was not an issue here, I could use the model below (using `R` code). (Here, I assume varying random intercepts and random slopes for both subject and item.)

```
lmer(look ~ iv1 * iv2 + (1 + iv1*iv2 | subject) + (1 + iv1*iv2 | item), 
     family = "binomial", data=data)
```

However, given that participants listened to sentences each of which lasted a few seconds, where they looked at (left vs. right) would vary across time. So one way to model time might be to include `time` as a covariate (it may even be necessary to natural polynomials):

```
lmer(look ~ iv1 * iv2 + time + (1 + iv1*iv2 | subject) + (1 + iv1*iv2 | item), 
     family = "binomial", data=data)
```

But things get complicated since (1) it is possible that `time` interacts `v1` and `v2` and (2) I probably need to somehow model `time` in the random effect terms. An additional complication is that eye-tracking data is fairly large. The particular set of data that I am working with currently has 5 million rows, so running even the simplest multilevel logistic regression can be fairly time consuming.

So my question is, given my design, what would be a good way to model time.

Comment: What exactly is `iv1` and `iv2` ? Maybe I am looking it in a wrong way, but are you sure you need this random effect structure? (aside the "keeping it maximal" rationale) You allow for correlation between the intercept deviations of `item` (or `subject`) and the  `iv1*iv2` effect deviations within the levels of `item`. Those are a lot of parameters... Maybe just `(time| item)` (and `subject` obviously) are enough to test your assumptions? (`time` and `1 + time` are equivalent specifications by the way) Check your model residuals.